# Dell Studio 1737 - Windows re-install fails after using Win7 all-in-one installer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, bios, boot

My kid stepped on my Win7Ultimate install disk, so used an install disk (all-in-one - has all versions)from a friend to re-install, and now that I want to go back to XP, I can't re-install any other operating system (including win7) except from the aio installer.

My question is whether this is an installer with a virus, or whether my Pheonix BIOS is corrupted.   I have completely wiped the hard drive using the 0 pass method, and still won't re-install anything.

My research suggests that it might be the BIOS as message says not recognized system (when using DELL install disks), or just blue screens with a stop error (on Win98 & XP Pro Install Disks - OEM Disks).   There is something about a bit that stops changes in the BIOS (sorry, not that up on inside technology), and was thinking this could be it, but entirely unsure.

I just recently tried to update the BIOS to A08 and didn't appear to be any problems.  I can access all parameters in setup including the option to lock out any changes.  It lists the BIOS as A08, so any suggestions as to where to go (with my laptop - LOL) would be greatly appreciated.

J.B.

Comment: The media you used was not legit. So any problems you might have should be expected. Its not exactly clear what is preventing you from installing WIndows XP. What I can tell you its neither a virus nor a corrupted BIOS.  There are legal ways to get a copy of Windows 7 your friend giving you pirated software `all in one` media isn't one of those ways.

Comment: It was not an illegal copy.  It was an installer.  I had to enter my product key from the back of the computer.

Comment: I have a dell studio with dell install disks for xp pro, vista, windows 7 Ultimate (the broken one).   All three install disks came with this computer (Dell repaired unit multiple times, and I ended with different OS disks every time they sent it back.

Comment: When using the OEM disks, after start of install it gets a stop message and says my computer is not a dell system.    That's what makes me think the BIOS is corrupted.   My service tag is also no longer resident in the BIOS.

Comment: Your BIOS is indeed corrupt.  Its extremely unlikely the media you used caused it though.  At this point you should contact Dell on how to repair the BIOS if its not longer being detected as a Dell.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the drive is indeed empty using something like GParted from a Linux LiveCD/USB, then try installing Linux. If that too fails your BIOS flash seems to have corrupted something. However if that works (and your question seems to indicate that the Win7 AIO works too), then I don't see how it could be a problem with your BIOS.

One possible cause of Dell's OEM discs stating that your computer is not a Dell system could be that they're looking for the Dell Recovery Partition or similar. Obviously you lack that now since you zero filled your drive.

Is there any reason you want to go back to XP? I recommend obtaining a genuine Win7 key and sticking to that if it works (you don't need to use the AIO, just download a copy from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)). Support for XP will end in another 9 months or so and it will stop receiving any security updates/patches after that. If you *must* go back to XP though for some reason, contacting Dell to get this resolved is your best bet.